# Publishing messages on HornetQ using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, hornetq

I'm developing a project wich is using HornetQ, and I want to publish some messages on it to execute a load test using JMeter. Does anyone here ever tried anything like it?

How can I configure JMeter to publish messages on HornetQ?

I already copied all the jars to the JMeter lib and filled all the fields on the "JMS Publisher Sampler". How can I proceed? Any example or JMX file which I could use as an example?

Comment: did you try what's explained on their user manual?

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-point-to-point-test-plan.html

Are you asking something more specific about configs?

Comment: Yeap, I tried exactly that. And it just didn't work :(

Comment: that's purely a jmeter question. I usually try to help every question on hornetq.. but it's out of my knowledge. hopefully someone will help here

Comment: Yeap, I noticed. Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about HornetQ. I advice you to take a look at all **samplers** in [standard component reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html), [JMeter Plugins](https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add HornetQ JARs to jmeter/lib folder

[image]

Then for configuration of JMS Sampler use this:

- http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/using-jms.html

Comment: Nice answer!.. just a note, use the latest version available beyond 2.2.5